# How to find duplicate log events in Splunk

Tags: logging, splunk, splunk-query

I'm trying to query my Splunk logs to find duplicate data, but am unable to find the right query.

Example logs:

```
{"time":"2021-07-08 02:16:17.9232","level":"debug","message":"update","parameters":{"id":["1"], other params...}}
{"time":"2021-07-08 02:17:17.9232","level":"debug","message":"update","parameters":{"id":["1"], other params...}}
```

The duplicate log events would have the same id parameter, but a different timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the desired field extracted, finding duplicates is a matter of counting the instances of each value of that field and displaying the ones with a count greater than one.

```
index=foo
| spath
| stats count by "parameters.id"
| where count > 1
```